# Highchart Json Not sommilar to conventional JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I want to make chart using high chart.
With ajax call I got format like:

```
[{ 'name':'Bananas', 'value':"8"},
        { 'name':'kiwi', 'value':"8"},
        { 'name':'mixed nuts', 'value':"8"},
        { 'name':'orange', 'value':"3"},
        { 'name':'pears', 'value':"2"},
       ]
```

But Hight chart needs:

```
[ ['Bananas', 8],
            ['Kiwi', 3],
            ['Mixed nuts', 1],
            ['Oranges', 6],
            ['Apples', 8],
            ['Pears', 4]

        ]
```

Is there any high chart method for converting json or sample code format to change json with highchart format.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't offer a method for that - it's user's responsibility to provide appropriately formatted data. Array format is not the only one available. Here's a documentation for all acceptable formats: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the data into the required format:

```js
const data = [{
    'name': 'Bananas',
    'value': "8"
  },
  {
    'name': 'kiwi',
    'value': "8"
  },
  {
    'name': 'mixed nuts',
    'value': "8"
  },
  {
    'name': 'orange',
    'value': "3"
  },
  {
    'name': 'pears',
    'value': "2"
  },
];

const result = data.map(item => [item.name, item.value]);
console.log(result);
```